# Running all PHPUnit tests for a project using Gradle

Tags: php, gradle, phpunit

I am trying to use PHPUnit to do unit testing on a project that is using Gradle.  Is it possible to download PHPUnit and run the tests using Gradle?

Comment: If Gradle can run shell commands, then yes. Use Composer to download PHPUnit, and then run the PHPUnit shell command. Settings can be put in a `phpunit.xml` file in the project root.

Comment: Have already see [this](https://github.com/eltrino/gradle-php-plugin) plugin? What do you think about?

Comment: Matteo this seems to be a good answer but can't confirm myself just yet. DarrenCibis does this work for you?